# Resources that classify words/definitions by period in Latin history?

Tags: vocabulary, dictionary, resource-request

I'm trying to develop a stronger sense of what/how Latin vocabulary was used at different points in the history of the language. In looking around Google and archive.org, I've found dictionaries from, say, the 19th century that contain only words Cicero used (e.g. the Lexicon Ciceronianum, in three volumes ([1](https://books.google.com/books?id=uO8wAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=lexicon%20ciceronianum&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj_uGumsPOAhWHkh4KHb0XDF8Q6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=lexicon%20ciceronianum&f=false), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=QRngAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=lexicon%20ciceronianum&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj_uGumsPOAhWHkh4KHb0XDF8Q6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=lexicon%20ciceronianum&f=false), and [3](http://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5Qac0W4wgz0os7ONfTCTLGqRLXq8eXtsBsDcSzUOBtDY1EUI9DSPGvjRVIET1RQtXO48ZH-hlz0HRXzXkcDikpaFwN1S56bkCyCHiXRzH9umceC8juVJAVvElhGQ4aaihTRX4ZOpqUCsjW9equvHY_AScifHezSOUuZxLfjdwm3qo1o_VBcUpZVFwQTzeBwrPAEZzsQFxXIFmLoYrbDzRAIMtTlmDSiioUWyjWmpCjTCFh6qmufIcT_dEu6i_H1Ethvbg6Vur))), but are there any modern dictionaries or dictionary-like resources that either

a) contain only Latin from certain ages (preferably Golden, Silver, or both),
b) classify entries by age, or
c) include information on age as part of a word's entry?

My main current aim is to develop a sense of the corpus of Golden Age vocabulary and what words meant at that time, as distinct from words that entered the language later or that changed their meaning over time.

But I can imagine all sorts of other ways in which such a dictionary/resource might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I am aware of the following online resources (Brill's Dictionary Platform). Caveat: **all of them are available by subscription only** (not free).

**[The Dictionary of Renaissance Latin from Prose Sources / Lexique de la prose latine de la Renaissance Online](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/hoven)**. This is how it is described on the website:

> "It records the vocabulary of over 230 Latin prose authors from different regional backgrounds who wrote between c. 1300 and c. 1600, and gives translations in French and English in approximately 11,000 entries."

**[Mediae Latinitatis Lexicon Minus Online](http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/niermeyer)**

> "It explores the post-classical Latin language of the Western European Middle Ages from 550 to 1150, tracing the development and use of words."
>
> "It provides French, English and German translations "for every entry of a Medieval Latin concept and searches on lemma and full text: searches can be refined by century of use."

Also, De Gruyter provides access to **[Thesaurus Linguae Latinae](http://www.degruyter.com/databasecontent?dbid=tll&dbsource=%2Fdb%2Ftll)** (**institutional subscription only**). It covers "all the Latin texts from the classical period up to about 600 A.D."